# Google MAP not displaying markers with custom labels

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know this is on me. My eyes already failed me on an earlier question where I simply missed a comma. Thankfully, an incorrect syntax error pointed me towards the fix, but now, no errors are given, map is being created, but no markers are being placed.

My xml file is being generated properly, as seen here [xml generated file](http://l3valuation.com/portal/maptest2.php), however nothing is showing up.  Can someone take a look at this code as a second set of eyes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>L3 CARDS</title>
    <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
    * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
    var customLabel = {
        1: {
            label: 'A'
        },
        2: {
            label: 'I'
        },
        3: {
            label: 'L'
        },
        4: {
            label: 'R'
        },
        5: {
            label: 'G'
        }
    };

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.3791021, -122.7613788),
            zoom: 15
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
        downloadUrl('maptest2.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
                var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
                var reporttype = markerElem.getAttribute('reporttype');
                var propertyname = markerElem.getAttribute('propertyname');
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng'))
                );
                var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
                var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                strong.textContent = propertyname
                infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
                infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                var text = document.createElement('text');
                text.textContent = propertyname
                infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                var icon = customLabel[reporttype] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    label: icon.label
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myAPIkey&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your latitude and longitude values are reversed.

Comment: geocodezip, you're a god.  I stared at the code for hours and never even thought of that.  please resubmit this as an answer so I can accept it.  It's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latitude and longitude values are reversed